# Easy RDF library is not returning proper RDF values

Tags: php, rdf, easyrdf

I have an remote RDF file from where I want to fetch some data. It is on remote server and the example data is working 100% fine, but soon I parse my file it starts giving the error.
I am using Easy RDF library.

Here is the example they are providing:

```
<?php
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../lib/');
    require_once "EasyRdf.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Basic FOAF example</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
  $foaf = EasyRdf_Graph::newAndLoad('http://njh.me/foaf.rdf');
  $me = $foaf->primaryTopic();
?>

<p>
  My name is: <?= $me->get('foaf:name') ?>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my example from where i am getting an error.

```
<?php
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../lib/');
    require_once "EasyRdf.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Basic FOAF example</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
  $foaf = EasyRdf_Graph::newAndLoad('http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/cache/generated/4500/pg4500.rdf');
  $me = $foaf->primaryTopic();
?>

<p>
  My name is: <?= $me->get('dcterms:title') ?>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Error i am getting:

```
My name is: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\giftcardbooks\easyrdf\examples\basic.php on line 31
```

My ultimate goal is to get values from the RDF file. using its nodes and child.
please have a look and help me out from it.

Comment: anyone for help please.

Comment: The error message says, that the `$me->get` does not exist, because `$me` is not an object. Try to dump that variable.

Comment: I guess the problem is that your file does not have a primary topic, but I am not sure yet.

Comment: I found [this about `foaf:primaryTopic`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_primaryTopic), but I am not sure how this lib finds that topic, or what happens when it cannot find one, or even is it possible that it cannot find one?! The documentation does not write anything useful. Try to ask here your question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/easyrdf

Comment: I think you should define a primaryTopic resource in your RDF or, refer to another resource which has a name.

Comment: thank you please for the help and comments.

Comment: i have dump the variable and it returns NULL

Comment: i need data of this node: <dcterms:title>Complete Project Gutenberg Works of George Meredith</dcterms:title>

Comment: and this node as well: <pgterms:name>Meredith, George</pgterms:name>

Comment: so actually i have an access to remote rdf and i just need to parse that to php for getting values i have shown you above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is far from complete, and it is very hard to find anything relevant in this topic. All you can do for further understanding is digging into the code, or asking your question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/easyrdf.

### The `primaryTopic()` approach will never work

According to the [Graph class](https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/blob/ca3918899fc25aa7f0773b65ea97b827c3aaec9b/lib/EasyRdf/Graph.php), the `primaryTopic()` does this:

```
        return $this->get(
            $resource,
            'foaf:primaryTopic|^foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf',
            'resource'
        );
```

Which means it is looking for a resource which is in some kind of relation with `foaf:primaryTopic`. Your `get()` call returns `null`, since your RDF does not contain a resource like that.

### Currently this works for me with your RDF

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic FOAF example</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/** @var EasyRdf_Graph $graph */
$graph = EasyRdf_Graph::newAndLoad('http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/cache/generated/4500/pg4500.rdf');

/** @var EasyRdf_Resource $book */
$book = $graph->resource('http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/cache/generated/4500/ebooks/4500'); //returns the ebook resource

$title = $book->get('dcterms:title'); //returns a literal node
?>

<p>
    My name is: <?php echo $title; //calls the __toString() of the literal node
?>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

An alternative approach to get the `$book`:

```
$book = current($graph->resources());
```

*Since the book is a root node, it will be the first resource in the graph...*

### I don't think there is a way to get the book using `pgterms:ebook`

It is because EasyRdf does not recognizes that as a type. I think that is because it is not defined anywhere as an `rdfs:Class`, it is just used, but that's just a guess, to make it sure you have to check the code. The `dcterms:title` is not a type either, but it can be used as a resource property...

```
var_dump($graph->types($book))
->
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
}
```

### Parse as XML

It is much easier to parse your RDF file with an XML parser:

```
$dom = simplexml_load_file('http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/cache/generated/4500/pg4500.rdf');
$title = (string) current($dom->xpath('//rdf:RDF/pgterms:ebook/dcterms:title'));
$name = (string) current($dom->xpath('//rdf:RDF/pgterms:ebook/dcterms:creator/pgterms:agent/pgterms:name'));
echo $title;
echo $name;
```

I think there is an issue in the EasyRdf or in your RDF file, but I could not find a way to get the name using EasyRdf. The `dcterms:creator` had an `rdf:type` of `pgterms:agent`, but it had no other properties nor had the agent... I could not find out what's the problem. I checked the `$graph->resources()` and the value of the missing properties were under generated IDs which seemed to have no contact with the `$ebook`. So I guess the parsing went not so well. This can be an EasyRdf error, or this can be a problem with the RDF file itself. I'll ask about it in the discussion forum, maybe they provide an answer.

Comment: here is the response please:: Warning: Missing argument 2 for EasyRdf_Graph::get(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\giftcardbooks\easyrdf\examples\basic.php on line 31 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\giftcardbooks\easyrdf\lib\EasyRdf\Graph.php on line 568

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: propertyPath in D:\xampp\htdocs\giftcardbooks\easyrdf\lib\EasyRdf\Graph.php on line 576

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message '$propertyPath should be a string or EasyRdf_Resource and cannot be null' in D:\xampp\htdocs\giftcardbooks\easyrdf\lib\EasyRdf\Graph.php:577 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\giftcardbooks\easyrdf\examples\basic.php(31): EasyRdf_Graph->get('pgterms:name') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\giftcardbooks\easyrdf\lib\EasyRdf\Graph.php on line 577

Comment: these are the responses.. i think we are getting closer but no sure why it is giving so much errors. once again thank you fro the help in getting through this error.

Comment: Yepp, I check it now on my dev machine.

Comment: Thank you please. kindly please download the rdf file as well in order to get the clear picture.

Comment: any solution please? i am sorry i am getting panic btw. :(

Comment: Thank You very much please. God bless you for the help.

Comment: Getting closer: `$graph->resource('pgterms:ebook');` returns an `EasyRdf_Resource` of the `pgterms:ebook`, which has the `dcterms:title` property. But no luck yet with getting the value of that property.

Comment: OMG may be we need to use `get->('dcterms:title')` for getting value. can you try this please. i mean something like above.

Comment: Nope, somehow the resource just create an empty resource and does not ask it from the graph, so that is not the right way. :S

Comment: i tried using `<?php
  $graph  = EasyRdf_Graph::newAndLoad('http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/cache/generated/4500/pg4500.rdf');
  $me    = $graph->resource('pgterms:ebook');
?>
<p>
  My name is: <?php echo $me->get('dcterms:title') ?>
</p>` but still no lucks..

Comment: Yes, the `pgterms:ebook` is the IRI of the resource type, but not a resource IRI, that's why it is not working...

Comment: its start giving much pain now, as they are also not providing much support on this.

Comment: In theory `$graph->allOfType('pgterms:ebook')` should work, but I guess it does not, because there is no ebook type defined in anywhere. I guess `dcterms:title` works, because it is a property, and we asking property instead of type. But that's just a guess... `$graph->type($book)` returns NULL btw.

Comment: thank you please. so how the code actually looks like? can you please share?

Comment: i have used: `echo $me    = $graph->resource('dcterms:title');` and it returns `http://purl.org/dc/terms/title` but we need value here. what do you say?

Comment: even it is not correct return as we do not have anything like that in the rdf file. :)

Comment: thank you very much please. thank you again for the time and great help. but can you please explain this? `$graph->resource('http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/cache/generated/4500/ebooks/4500');`

Comment: i mean `http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/cache/generated/4500/ebooks/4500` doesnot exists as directory on mirror ftp.

Comment: its not returning me the value for `<pgterms:name>Meredith, George</pgterms:name>` can you please look on it.?

Comment: please find the author name as well. from `<pgterms:name>`. please

Comment: Ofc. it does not exist, these URLs are just identifiers, nothing more... For example there is nothing under the namespace URLs either...

Comment: i see got your point Sir. thank you for the explanation please.

Comment: our one problem is 100% resolve now. i must seriously appreciate your great efforts with getting me through this issue. we need only name of authors now.

Comment: Check your RDF with an XML viewer: the `pgterms:name` is under the `pgterms:ebook/dcterms:creator/pgterms:agent/pgterms:name`...

Comment: you are saying 100% correct. so how can we get its value now?

Comment: kindly help me getting author name as well, so further if i need to get any more value i will simply follow this specific rule.

Comment: I am also thinking the same, how it can be possible the value is not coming using get();

Comment: i tried using `$title = $book->get('pgterms:ebook|dcterms:creator|pgterms:agent|pgterms:name'); //returns a literal node` and it returns `My name is: http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/cache/generated/12415/2009/agents/4353`..

Comment: no lucks? :) btw its really incomplete sort of library i think.

Comment: A serialized the graph as JSON-LD it shows, that the `dcterms:creator` has a type of `pgterms:agent`, and it has a property of `pgterms:name`. Its IRI is `http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/cache/generated/4500/2009/agents/520`.

Comment: :) so we need to do something else. :) it really getting so pain now. :(

Comment: According to the `resource->properties()` the `dcterms:creator` has only an `rdf:type` which is an agent. So I think the RDF is malformed, that's why it is not working... :S

Comment: ahhhhh i seee you meant to say there is some error in the RDF file?? like some typos regarding proper nodes and childs definations?

Comment: It is much easier to use an XML parser like SimpleXML and xpath to get the values you need.

Comment: but do you think RDF file mean this RDF file will work with SimpleXML and xpath??

Comment: I don't know what exactly is the problem, but I cannot retrieve the `pgterms:name` by using the `$book` node. I checked it in a JSON-LD format (which I am more familiar with), and the result graph had about 30 nodes, not just a single one (book) I expected.

Comment: Ofc it will work, it is a valid XML... It is a valid RDF too, but it seems to have flaws by describing your content, or EayRdf has errors by parsing this RDF (but I think the later is unlike).

Comment: Ok ok got you on this. can you provide some code on this or help related to this issue so we can resolve it using SimpleXML..

Comment: I edited my post, and added a SimpleXML example, I can do nothing more about this. Good luck!

Comment: I added a topic with title "Problems by traversing RDF graph" here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/easyrdf . It is not readable yet, maybe it waits for moderation, or it is denied to send in a new topic, I am not sure...

Comment: Thank you very very much for you great help so far with me. thank to stackoverflow having brilliant programmers in the site.

Comment: thank you for the example as well. i will give it a try.